# determine ulimit for root user

Tags: linux, solr, ulimit

we believe we have increased the max open file descriptors for the root user.  This was done by adding this line to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*         -    nofile            2048
```

We think we've confirmed that the root user's limit was increased because we can tell (not described here) that our application (solr - which is run by root) has 1098 files open.  However, we can't tell for sure how many open files the root user is allowed.  We would expect this command to work, but it doesn't seem to be:

```
$ sudo -u root -s "ulimit -Sn"
1024
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other entries for nofile in limits.conf?  Maybe it's being overridden.  What about possible parsing errors of limits.conf.  Can you attach your entire file?

Comment: Are you running selinux?  What is the output from:
  ls -lZ /etc/security/limits.conf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the PID of the process that `solr` is running and then `cat /proc/$SOLR_PID/limits` -- this will tell you the actual limits of the process.

I'd recommend to run things like `solr` as a seperated unprivileged user. When doing this you have multiple options ([*limits.conf*](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=limits.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) or add a `ulimit -n 2048` to the init script, ...). The last one isn't all that shiny but works for quick settings and restarting the daemon

RANT: don't tell me you can't restart becauso you'll lose service. If that is the case you should have a HA setup anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

After changing number of open files in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, user must log out and log back in to take effect. So, try this:

```
$ sudo su -
# ulimit -Sn
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has an answer, but that looks more like a work around, not a real solution.

According to ubuntu this is not a bug but a documentation issue, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/65244

*Thanks for your report. As you said this is not a bug in pam but a documentation issue.
The fact to allow explicitly allow limits for user root has been addressed a while ago (30 Aug 2000) but you need to explicitly name user root to apply the limits.*

So if you want to change the ulimit on all users, including the root user you have to specify:

```
*         -    nofile            2048
root      -    nofile            2048
```